# Bootstrap: Validation states with form-inline fields?

Tags: validation, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any way to use Bootstrap's form field validation states/classes (`warning`, `error`, `info`, `success`) on `form-inline` fields (*without using `control-group`*)?

---

I'm using Bootstrap, and I have a large form that uses the `form-horizontal` class for layout. However, there are areas within the form where the fields need to be inline (for example, City/State/Zip). I'm using `form-inline` for this, which works fine. Here's the basic markup:

```
<form id="account-form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="" novalidate>
    <!-- Address -->
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Address</label>

        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" name="address" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- City, State, Zip -->
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">City</label>

        <div class="controls form-inline">
            <input type="text" name="city" />

            <label>State</label>
            <input type="text" name="state" />

            <label>Zip Code</label>
            <input type="text" name="zipcode" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

In my particular situation I need to handle validation manually. Unfortunately, it seems Bootstrap's validation state classes must be applied to the `control-group`; as you can see in the example above, the `control-group` in my case contains multiple fields. I tried wrapping individual fields within `control-group` spans or divs, but `control-group` does not play nicely at all when used with both a `form-inline` and `form-horizontal` together!

Is there a CSS class or other rule I can attach to a field directly (or an otherwise-innocent field wrapper) to apply these styles to individual fields, without having to completely redeclare all the standard bootstrap styles??

Comment: it seems you can't https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/5248

Comment: With b.e. https://github.com/moagrius/copycss you can copy css styles. You can use this, see: http://bootply.com/BassJobsen/61942 Note you need a state class to copy from and you can't copy :hover, :focus etc. states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create some custom less code and recompile bootstrap:

Add `@import "_custom.less";` to less/bootstrap.less

create **less/_custom.less**:

```
// Mixin for inline form field states
.inlineformFieldState(@warning: success,@textColor: #555, @borderColor: #ccc, @backgroundColor: #f5f5f5) {
  // Set the text color
  label.@{warning},
  .help-block .@{warning},
  .help-inline .@{warning}{
    color: @textColor;
  }
  // Style inputs accordingly
  .checkbox .@{warning},
  .radio .@{warning},
  input.@{warning},
  select.@{warning},
  textarea.@{warning} {
    color: @textColor;
  }
  input.@{warning},
  select.@{warning},
  textarea.@{warning} {
    border-color: @borderColor;
    .box-shadow(inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075)); // Redeclare so transitions work
    &:focus {
      border-color: darken(@borderColor, 10%);
      @shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 6px lighten(@borderColor, 20%);
      .box-shadow(@shadow);
    }
  }
  // Give a small background color for input-prepend/-append
  .input-prepend .add-on .@{warning},
  .input-append .add-on .@{warning} {
    color: @textColor;
    background-color: @backgroundColor;
    border-color: @textColor;
  }
}

.form-inline{
  .inlineformFieldState(success, @successText, @successText, @successBackground);
  .inlineformFieldState(warning, @warningText, @warningText, @warningBackground);
  .inlineformFieldState(info, @infoText, @infoText, @infoBackground);
  .inlineformFieldState(error, @errorText, @errorText, @errorBackground);
}
```

This mixin is based on `.formFieldState` in less/mixins.less. After recompile bootstrap you could use (see also: http://jsfiddle.net/bassjobsen/K3RE3/):

```
<form>
<div class="container">
   <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls form-inline">
            <label class="error">City</label>
            <input class="error" type="text" name="city" />
            <label class="warning">State</label>
            <input class="warning" type="text" name="state" />
            <label class="success">Zip Code</label>
            <input class="success" type="text" name="zipcode" />
            <label class="info">Street</label>
            <input class="info" type="text" name="street" />
        </div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this, remove control-group  from div container and use form-group instead, but put this in  each input div, I do not secure that works with control-group.
 This url maybe can help you http://formvalidation.io/examples/complex-form/, this not work for me  ^_^!.I hope help you.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="col-lg-4 form-group" >
            <select class="form-control" name="pais">
                <option value="" selected disabled>Pais</option>
                <option value="a">A</option>
                <option value="b">B</option>
                <option value="c">C</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 form-group" >
            <select class="form-control" name="estado">
                <option value="" selected disabled>Estado</option>
                <option value="a">A</option>
                <option value="b">B</option>
                <option value="">C</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 form-group">
            <select class="form-control"  name="ciudad">
                <option value="" selected disabled>Ciudad</option>
                <option value="a">A</option>
                <option value="b">B</option>
                <option value="c">C</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not what user is asking.

Answer (score 0):

something like this will work.

```
<script>
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');

        //******** added custom code.
        $('input[type="radio"]').closest('.col-sm-9').find('.invalid-feedback').hide();
        $('input[type="radio"]:invalid').closest('.col-sm-9').find('.invalid-feedback').show();
      }, false);
        //******** added custom code.
    });
  }, false);
})();
</script>
```

code above is almost of document, added custom code at the end of submit event listener.

@read
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#validation